# How to create a Multi widgets Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4

Is it possible to develop an application with a multitude of interfaces (widgets), where each widget has its own .cpp and .h file? If so, can you suggest a way to do that?

I am aware of the stacked widget way but this method doesn't allow me to separate the code of each page from the others.

I need to have the general structure of my application to be similar to an android application developed in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can create widgets separately, then, dynamically construct `QStackedWidget` and add widgets to it using `addWidget` method

PS. you can also use widget promotion, to have `QStackedWidget` be created by QtDesigner and filled with your widgets
 http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/designer-using-custom-widgets.html

Comment: do you have any tutorial about that ??

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
look here. Try to combine information in both links with documentation. I haven't seen tutorial on your subject. Just create widgets like in tutorial, then create main `QStackedWidget`, and promote its pages to your widgets